# Using regular expressions to manipulate strings

Tags: python, regex, string

So I have a string in the format of `ABCD-EFGH-IJ` where `A` through `J` are numbers `0-9` in a list of a ton of other strings. I have a regular expression identifying it, but how do I get it to also replace it with the format `IJABCDEFGH`?

Comment: Have you tried to do something yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression with substitution:

```
import re
s = '1234-5678-90'
print re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})', r'\3\1\2', s)
```

Result:

```
9012345678
```

`\3` matches the content of what inside the third pair of parentheses. So `\3\1\2` means to replace with the third group of your numbers, followed by the first followed by the second.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This clears up things a lot! Is there a good source you refer to, to learn relative expressions?